# receiving ORA-00913: too many values when trying to insert a row using visual studio

Tags: c#, oracle, visual-studio

so testing a windows service I'm building where I connect to an oracle database, select some data then insert this data into a second oracle database. both connections connect without issue , I can see the selected data but when trying to insert it I receive the error: ORA-00913: too many values. I checked both the select and the insert both contain 16 values so I'm not sure what's causing the error.

```
            using (OracleConnection sourceConnection = new OracleConnection(sourceConnectionString))

                try
                {
                    {
                        sourceConnection.Open();
                        Console.WriteLine("Connected ");
                        Console.WriteLine("Passed source connection.");
                        targetConnection.Open();
                        Console.WriteLine("Connected ");
                        Console.WriteLine("Passed target connection.");
                        
                        using (OracleCommand selectCommand = new OracleCommand("SELECT EMPLID, AGENCY_EMPLID as WORK_FOR_AGENCY_EMPLID, busniess_unit as WORK_FOR_AGENCY, EMPL_STATUS, LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME, MIDDLE_NAME, DEPTID, DEPT_DESCR, JOBCODE,    JOBCODE_DESCR, B_SAFETY_SENSTV, HR_STATUS, POSITION_NBR, POSNUM_DESCR, hire_dt from user_table    where bsc_emplid = '1028277'", sourceConnection))
                        using (OracleDataReader reader = selectCommand.ExecuteReader())
                        {

                            using (OracleCommand insertCommand = new OracleCommand("INSERT INTO USER_TABLE_STAGE (EMPLID, WORK_FOR_AGENCY_EMPLID, WORK_FOR_AGENCY, EMPL_STATUS, LAST_NAME, FIRST_NAME, MIDDLE_NAME, DEPTID, DEPT_DESCR, JOBCODE, JOBCODE_DESCR, B_SAFETY_SENSTV, HR_STATUS, POSITION_NBR, POSNUM_DESCR, HIRE_DT)VALUES(:val1, :val2, :val3, :val4, :val5, :val6, :val6, :val7, :val8, :val9, :val10, :val1, :val12, :val3, :val14, :val15, :val16)", targetConnection))  
                            {
                               
                                while (reader.Read())
                                {
                                    insertCommand.BindByName = true;
                                   
                                    insertCommand.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":val1", reader["EMPLID"]));
                                    insertCommand.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":val2", reader["WORK_FOR_AGENCY_EMPLID"]));
                                    insertCommand.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":val3", reader["WORK_FOR_AGENCY"]));
                                    insertCommand.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":val4", reader["EMPL_STATUS"]));
                                    insertCommand.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":val5", reader["LAST_NAME"]));
                                    insertCommand.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":val6", reader["FIRST_NAME"]));
                                    insertCommand.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":val7", reader["MIDDLE_NAME"]));
                                    insertCommand.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":val8", reader["DEPTID"]));
                                    insertCommand.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":val9", reader["DEPT_DESCR"]));
                                    insertCommand.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":val10", reader["JOBCODE"]));
                                    insertCommand.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":val11", reader["JOBCODE_DESCR"]));
                                    insertCommand.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":val12", reader["B_SAFETY_SENSTV"]));
                                    insertCommand.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":val13", reader["HR_STATUS"]));
                                    insertCommand.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":val14", reader["POSITION_NBR"]));
                                    insertCommand.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":val15", reader["POSNUM_DESCR"]));
                                    insertCommand.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":val16", reader["hire_dt"]));
                                    insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                    Console.WriteLine("inserted record.");

                                }
                                insertCommand.Parameters.Clear();
                            }

                        }


                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("error: " + ex.Message);
                }
```

Comment: Could it be this? `:val10, :val1, :val12, :val3, :val14`

Comment: Double check the placeholder list of your `INSERT` statement, `val6` is doubled, and `val11` and `val13` appear to have typos.

Answer (score 1):

You have more values than columns: twice ":val6, :val6," could be the source of the problem.